# HttpServletRequest - API REST

Tags: java, mysql, spring, rest

this is a very noob question. I have a project to do that exemplifies the use of RESTFUL APIs. I am using java spring + MySQL and JSPs for front-end. My question is this. Does `HttpServletRequest` use `REST`? 
For example, I have one controller with this method in it:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/list_events", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String navigateToEventList(HttpServletRequest request){

    request.setAttribute("events",eventService.getAll());
    return "listevents";
}
```

I have the controller class annotated with `@Controller`. If I swap it to `@RestController`, it stops working. So, am I using rest in this method for example? And if not, what should I use?

And in my jsp file this is what I have for example:

```
 <c:forEach var="event" items="${events}">

        <tr>

            <td>${event.id}</td>
            <td>${event.title}</td>
            <td>${event.description}</td>
            <td>${event.type}</td>
            <td>${event.date}</td>
            <td>${event.location}</td>

        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSP is used when the client needs to display the contents in HTML (web-browser). RESTful web-services used when the client is some other application accepting data responses (it maybe the JavaScript in browser or some other application).

> I have the controller class adnotated with @Controller. If I swap it
>   to @RestController, it stops working.

If you swap it to `@RestController` the response intended to be JSON, or XML.
You can achieve the same result with annotation `@Controller` your calss and `@ResponseBody` on each of the methods (if you need mix of REST and non-REST responses).

What you're doing now is returning the HTML/JSP page to your browser, and it's not a RESTful web-service - it's the first case I described above.

> Does HttpServletRequest use REST?

REST means **Representational state transfer**, and it's architectural style of the application. 
`HttpServletRequest` it's just a requested body from current API. It can be used as either in RESTful or in non-RESTful servces.